# Android Bluetooth File Sharing Stream

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi I have this method to send a file via Bluetooth is working well. I was wondering if I can use this to receive it and play it at the same time like streaming via Bluetooth. In other words play it instead of saving it.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == DISCOVER_DURATION && requestCode == REQUEST_BLU) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "one.mp3");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));

            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            if(appsList.size() > 0) {
                String packageName = null;
                String className = null;
                boolean found = false;

                for(ResolveInfo info : appsList) {
                    packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
                    if(packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")) {
                        className = info.activityInfo.name;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth havn't been found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```